# Translate modal confirm buttons in arabic Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to translate modal confirm buttons in arabic? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your translation like this.

OK,موافق,module,Magento_GiftMessage

Reference :

https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_ar_sa/blob/master/ar_SA.csv

Flush Magento cache

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Already added. Not working